# Coloring Graph with some constarints

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, combinations, coloring

if Graph G be a Cycle with Length=4. how many ways we can color this graph with at most $\lambda$ different color, in such a way that non of two adjacent vertex has a same color?

Comment: Is there more to $G$ than the 4-cycle you mentioned?  Or is that the entire graph $G$?

Comment: Dear @paw88789, i correct it.

Comment: I have one more question: Do you count rotations and reflections of a coloring as the same or different?  (For instance if the vertices are $a,b,c,d$ and the cycle is $abcd$, would the coloring red, blue, green, blue be considered same or different compared to the coloring blue, red, blue, green?

Comment: Dear @paw88789, tha last answer is $ \lambda^4 - 4\lambda^3 + 6\lambda^2 - 3\lambda$. but i couldent understand how get it..

Comment: There is an algorithm for doing this kind of thing given in Section 7 of http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/ccooper/Discrete/CHAP07%20Graph%20Algorithms.pdf --- Example 11 is your problem exactly. Why not have a look at it and then write it up as an answer and post it here?

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson, i coudlent understand the example 11? would u please describe it?

Comment: I hope you read the exposition leading up to Example 11. What you're calculating is what's called *the chromatic polynomial*. The exposition shows you how to express the chromatic polynomial of a graph in terms of two simpler graphs, and then Example 11 applies that to your graph.

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson, would you please describe it for me?

Comment: Describe what, exactly? Do you have a specific question about something you read in that document?

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Dear @GerryMyerson, yes.

Comment: Good. So, how are you coming along with that document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cycle is $abcd$, where $a,b,c,d$ are vertices of the graph, the possible coloring patterns are $xyxy$, $xyxz$, $xyzy$, $xyzw$ where $x,y,z,w$ are different colors. (Of course if you only have $\lambda=2 \text{ or } 3$ colors available, not all these patterns are achievable.)

For the first pattern, choose a color for $x$, choose a color for $y$.  This can be done in $\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)$ ways.

For the second pattern, choose a color for $x$, a color for $y$, a color for $z$.  This can be done in $\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda -2)$ ways. (Note: If $\lambda<3$, this works out to $0$, which makes sense.

The third and fourth patterns are similar.

I think you end up with $\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)+\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda -2)+\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda -2)+\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)\cdot(\lambda -2)\cdot(\lambda-3)$, which should be equal to your answer.

Comment: Dear @Paw, how you get the last result as same as me ?

Comment: You'd have to multiply everything out and collect like terms.  One thing that might help would be to start by factoring out a common factor of $\lambda\cdot(\lambda-1)$.

Comment: i do it, but not as same as my answer !!

Comment: there is typo. please correct

Comment: Expression $=\lambda(\lambda-1)[1+2\lambda-4+(\lambda-2)(\lambda-3)]=\lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2-3\lambda+3)=\lambda^4-4\lambda^3+6\lambda^2-3\lambda$. For some reason, this editor, keeps messing up some of the lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the vertices of the cycle are $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$, in that order. You can choose a color for $w$ in $\lambda$ different ways.  After choosing the color for $w$, you can choose a color for $x$ in $\lambda-1$ different ways. Now you have two possible choices for $y$:

1. color it the same as $w$ (in 1 way), or
2. color it a different color than $w$ (in $\lambda-1$ ways).

In case (1), you have $\lambda-1$ choices of color for $z$, and so there are $\lambda \cdot (\lambda-1)\cdot 1 \cdot (\lambda-1)$ ways to color. In case (2), you have $\lambda-2$ choices of color for $z$, and so there are $\lambda \cdot (\lambda-1) \cdot (\lambda -1) \cdot (\lambda-2)$ ways to color. So in total you have:

\begin{array}\\
\lambda(\lambda-1)^2 + \lambda (\lambda-1)(\lambda-2)^2 &= \lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda-1 + (\lambda-2)^2)) \\
&= \lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda^2 - 3 \lambda + 3) \\
&= \lambda^4 -4\lambda^3 + 6 \lambda^2 - 3 \lambda
\end{array}